# Yii2 is it possible to toggle onmotion/yii2-widget-apexcharts series by default?

Tags: javascript, yii2, apexcharts

I am using onmotion/yii2-widget-apexcharts. In my chart I have series with ~ 20 data sets but I don't want show them all after page loads (like it's toggled off), instead it would be nice if chart could show only selected series names with option toggle those who are hidden. Primary need is to toggle all series off when page loads, perfect need is toggle off selected series. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable specific `series_name` by adding JS code to the widget initialization. `id` is generated, so it can help to specify it explicitly.

```
<?= ApexchartsWidget::widget([
    ...merge your existing code...,
    'chartOptions' => [
        'chart' => [
            'id' => 'your_chart_id',
        ],
    ],
    'js' => new JsExpression("ApexCharts.exec('your_chart_id', 'hideSeries', 'series_name')"),
]); ?>
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your response. I'm not sure where can I add this code. Mby if you have a little time for me to tell more how to add this piece of code?

Comment: I've updated the sample code. Open your view, look for `ApexchartsWidget` and merge my code there.

Comment: no, i have this error "Setting unknown property: onmotion\apexcharts\ApexchartsWidget::js"

Comment: I just now found your pull request on that widget and now it works with single series. Is it possible to hide multiple series? If yes, could you please tell me how?